# How to add minutes and hours to a string in MomentJs

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs

If I have a string like '15:30', how can I transform it into '17:10'?
I tried to do the following:

```
time = '15:30'
moment(time)
  .add(40, 'minutes')
  .add(2, 'hours')
  .format('HH:mm')
```

But it didn't work, and it outputs the error "invalid date".

Comment: Why use a deprecated library when you can simply split the string into two parts, and then perform the minutes + hours calculations separately?

Comment: Agree with @Terry, but instead of moment.js you can use dayjs (this is very similar) https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to parse the string data, we know we're using a valid hour.

```js
const time = '15:30' // Valid date
const time = '252:10' // Invalid date
```

You can use a second parameter in the moment function, something like this:

```js
moment(time, "HH:mm");
```

You simply need to know what format to convert your string to, [read more about that in this documentation link.](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Then, you can occupy the different builders to get the expected result.

```js
moment(time, "HH:mm") // Parse the string
  .add(40, 'minutes') // Add 40 minutes
  .add(2, 'hours') // Add 2 hours
  .format('HH:mm') // Format to specified format
```

And finally you will get your date time parsed.

Here is a working version of this:

```js
const time = '15:30'
const date = moment(time, "HH:mm").toDate();

const parsedDate = moment(date)
  .add(40, 'minutes')
  .add(2, 'hours')
  .format('HH:mm')

console.log(parsedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Parsing as moment object -> converting to date -> building a moment object from the date is just roundabout and unneeded. You already have the moment object, so why not use it? `moment("15:30", "HH:mm").add(40, 'minutes').add(2, 'hours').format('HH:mm')`

Comment: This is right, I wrote it separately to emphasize that you need to convert the string date to a real date, for that reason I use the same "moment.js" to convert.

Comment: You don't *need* to convert to a real date.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Adding 2 hours and 30 minutes to 15:30h will get you 18:10h - also without using moments.js:

```js
const time=new Date(2022,1,1,15,30); // define initial datetime object
time.setHours(time.getHours()+2);
time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes()+40);
console.log(time.toTimeString().slice(0,5));
```

Another way of solving the problem, involving a `Date.prototype` definition could be:

```js
Date.prototype.add=function(n,unit){ this["set"+unit](+this["get"+unit]()+n); return this; }

console.log(new Date(2022,1,1,15,30)
                 .add(2,"Hours")
                 .add(40,"Minutes")
                 .toTimeString()
                 .slice(0,5) );
```

Before the protest comes in from all sides: Yes, I get it: extending the prototype of a built in class is not considered good programming style. The above example should therefore be seen as a demonstration of how the prototype function mechanism works in JavaScript and should probably not be incorporated in real projects.